# Plotting graph with respect to frequency

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am doing a project on Open Modelica and i have to simulate filters on it using active elements(op amp). Modelica plots graph with respect to time but i want my graphs with respect to frequency to analyze the frequency response of the system. I searched the internet but couldn't find anything useful. Please reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to plot a variable with respect to another variable you can use plotParameteric from OMShell (OpenModelica Shell). In OMEdit (OpenModelica Connection Editor) you can click on parametric plot button x(y) and then select 2 variables.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you want is a [Bode plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot).  If so, it is important to understand that such a plot does not arise from a transient simulation.  It is necessary to transform your system into a linear, time-invariant representation in order to express the response of your system in the frequency domain.

I do not know what specific features OpenModelica has in this regard.  But those are at least the kinds of things you should search the documentation for.  If you have access to MATLAB, then all you really need to do is extract the linearized version of the model (normally expressed as the so-called "ABCD" matrices) and MATLAB can get you the rest of the way.

There is also the [Modelica_LinearSystems2](https://github.com/modelica/Modelica_LinearSystems2) library which might be compatible with OpenModelica (I have no idea).  It includes many types of operations you would typically perform on linear systems.